# Sitecore Unicorn Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403)

Tags: unicorn, serialization

We are seeing below exception when we run the pipeline step to sync_unicorn from Azure devops.
We checked the sharedsecret value being passed and that is existing in the config and both are matching.

```
2023-05-17T03:26:16.7383496Z ==============================================================================
2023-05-17T03:26:17.6530439Z Generating script.
2023-05-17T03:26:17.6594888Z Formatted command: . 'D:\a\r1\a\_ Develop Build Pipeline\sitecore9x\unicornsync\Sync.ps1' -url  'https://*********.net/unicorn.aspx' -secret '***'

                                 Sync-Unicorn: Executing Sync...
    2023-05-17T03:26:18.9637504Z Sync-Unicorn : Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) 
    2023-05-17T03:26:18.9637786Z Forbidden."
    2023-05-17T03:26:18.9638044Z At D:\a\r1\a\_Develop Build Pipeline\sitecore9x\unicornsync\Sync.ps1:11 char:1
    2023-05-17T03:26:18.9639182Z + Sync-Unicorn -ControlPanelUrl $url -SharedSecret $secret
    2023-05-17T03:26:18.9639607Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2023-05-17T03:26:18.9641981Z     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Sync-Unicorn], MethodInvocationException
    2023-05-17T03:26:18.9642315Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException,Sync-Unicorn
    2023-05-17T03:26:18.9642460Z
```

Comment: Check this one - https://www.sitecorevarun.com/2020/06/sitecore-habitat-home-sync-unicorn.html

Comment: Try adding ` -DebugSecurity` switch in `Sync.ps1`

Comment: I did make changes to enable debug security and I am able to see MAC and such details in the devops logs. How do I cross verify them with Sitecore. For some reason I don't see these logged in Sitecore logs

Comment: Did you ever some up with solution to this? I faced a similar issue.

Comment: @DeanOBrien I didn't yet. Please let me know if you come across any solution for this..